# In Google Sheets, how do I math (value per hour) with durations over 24 hours?

Tags: google-sheets, time, google-sheets-formula

I have durational times that run over 24 hours, but the hour() function returns as a reset (i.e. `=hour(25:36:05)` returns 1). I want to then sum said hour by another cell, specifically to find value per duration, times units.

[image: See Image Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HOUR()` gets the hour of a day from date-time value which is stored as a number. So, `HOUR()` gives you modulo 24-hours sorta say.

Use instead this formula to get number of hours:

```
=INT(S2 * 24)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this:

```
=VALUE(S2)*T2
```

[image]

---

to get duration hours you can use:

```
=TEXT(S2; "[h]")
```

[image]

Comment: OP wants to get 25 from `S2`.

Comment: @kishkin indeed. I find myself rarely reading what op asks xD

Comment: same :) changed my answer 3 times in 10 minutes recently.